# What library can you use to detect personalities from comments?

Tags: machine-learning

I have a bunch of comments from my website that I want to use to build a profile of someone's personality based on the topics they chose to write in and the their specific comments.

I know that this entails natural language processing but I have no idea where to start. I am  a python enthusiast so prefer the library being python.

I'm open to commercial libraries as well but prefer to learn how to do this successfully.

Comment: This is not an easy task.  Baidu (aka China's state-sponsored version of google) is paying millions to develop that capability.  I personally think they are going to call it "great firewall 2.0 - precrime against potential actors/leaders".  bottom line: there isn't a textbook solution for this that is "guaranteed", yet.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs to Cross-Validated. See, https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/468/how-to-differentiate-when-to-ask-question-about-machine-learning-topics-in-cross